# Input size different on other OS

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

The following form looks fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on OS X, iPhone & Android. The text input fields are a little bigger in Safari and Firefox compared to Chrome, but overall everything looks fine.

Firefox in Lubuntu however decides to almost **double the width of the input field**. It breaks out of the `div` block.

*One solution would be to set the width of the input fields in CSS*. This means that every different size needs another block of CSS. It's easier to edit the width of multiple text input type fields this way, however, every other width would require another block of CSS code.

That's why I would like to explore the other possibilities.

- Can I set the width of "1 size" somewhere? Eg: `<input type="text" size="15" />` and `1 size-width = 10px;` should render a text input field 150px wide.
- Can I include a second font-family that is supported and looks fine?
- Can I make the input type not break out of it's `div`?

Please note that I'm looking for an easy and elegant solution that is **not** *"setting a fixed text input width"*. If you think there is no other solution, please argue why.

```css
body{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1050px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
h3{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.leftmenu{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #666666;
}
```

```html
<form action="login/submit" method="post">
  <div class="leftmenu">
    <h3>Log in</h3>
    Naam: <br />
    <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /> <br />
    <br />
    Wachtwoord: <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="login_form" value="login" />
    <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a reset css file to see if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Since I never heard of reset CSS file before, I looked it up and found some examples. If I'm correct, a reset CSS file is a large collection of attributes set to the expected default values? I'm going to try that out now and let you know what my findings are. Any idea which specific attribute it might be?

Comment: That's right, usually makes elements appear the same over a variety of browsers etc. If it works, you can take out the parts you need or leave it linked as a separate file

Comment: It seems that the font-family for input gets set to the system default font-family (which is Ubuntu). Overriding it with Arial gets rid of the Ubuntu font, but the width stays. For now, I have set `input[type="text"] { max-width: 90%; }` to avoid that the field breaks out of its parent (in this case div).